# Condition to check existence of joined entity in Doctrine 2.1

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

I have two entities in Doctine 2.1 with OneToOne Bidirectional relationship.

```
Foo              |   Bar
--------------   |   --------------
id:    integer   |   id:    integer
value: integer   |   value: boolean
bar:   Bar       |   foo:   Foo
```

So that:

```
Foo.bar > 1...0 > Bar
```

I want to select all Foo records using Query Builder or DQL where

1. `Foo.value > :value`

   **OR**
2. `Foo.bar` is not empty, i.e. there is a `Bar` entity for this `Foo` entity

How do i do this?

I'm using code like this:

```php
$builder
    ->select('F')
    ->from('Foo', 'F')
    ->where('F.value > :value')
    ->orWhere('F.bar ???')
;
```

DQL solution will also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think *IS NOT NULL* is what your looking for.

In DQL :

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT f FROM Foo f WHERE F.value > :value OR F.bar IS NOT NULL');
```